# How should controller get the data edit and submit by HtmlBox?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am going to implement following function:
As front-end tool, HtmlBox is used to edit text data and then transmit these data to back-end controller to save in database.

My question is:
How could the back-end controller receive the data edit and submit by HtmlBox?

According to the common coding way of Spring MVC I used, One class called Data is created with a private member variable named "articleContent", the same as the textarea id in the web page the HtmlBox embeded in. In my opinion, when the object of Data class is passed into the Controller as a parameter and the form, contain a HtmlBox with text data in it, is submitted, the data should be got by the controller easily as a String variable? But the fact isn't like this, the data object's articleContent is null?

How should controller get the data?

Answer (score 0):

I have obtained the answwer of this question by myself!

In the front end Jsp view, the textarea enhanced by HtmlBox must use the "name" property or both "name" and "id" properties instead of "id" property alone! For instance:

```
<textarea id="theHtmlBoxName" name="theHtmlBoxName"></textarea>
```

In the back end controller, code as one of following:

```
public String saveTheHtmlBoxContent(@RequestParam String theHtmlBoxName){...};
```

or

```
public String saveTheHtmlBoxContent(HttpServletRequest request){
 String data = request.getParameter("theHtmlBoxName");...};
```

Kenneth